# Restangular and local storage

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, angular-ui-router, restangular

```
$stateProvider.state( 'clientinfo', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/clientinfo',
    resolve: {
        clients: ['Restangular','localStorageService',function(Restangular,localStorageService){
          var clients = localStorageService.get('clients');
          if(clients == null) {
             return Restangular.all('clients').getList().then(function(result){
             localStorageService.add('clients',result);
             angular.copy(result, clients);
          });
          return clients;
        }]
    }
    ......
}
```

Im trying to use localStorage and restangular but on initial page load my clients object is not returning the actual GET response but instead a null object, although my local storage is getting set correctly.

This code is working as aspected though just without local storage:

```
$stateProvider.state( 'clientinfo', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/clientinfo',
    resolve: {
        clients: ['Restangular',function(Restangular){
             return Restangular.all('clients').getList();
        }

    }
 .....
}
```

Any help? Thanks

Im using this module for local storage: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage
Restangular : https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Answer (score 3):

The version without localStorage works because Restangular calls return promises, which the `$state` service will resolve before finalizing the transition and loading up your controllers.

However, in your initial example, your `then()` isn't returning a value, so the resolution of the resulting promise (which is what you're returning) is `null`. If you remove your `angular.copy()` call and return `result`, it should work fine.